# How to call an error action from redux_epic?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to do like so:

```dart
Stream<dynamic> searchEpic(
  Stream<PerformSearchAction> actions,
  EpicStore<AppState> store,
) {
  return actions.asyncMap((action) => fetchPost()
      .then((results) => SearchResultsAction(results['title']))
      .catchError((error) => SearchErrorAction(error.message)));
}
```

However I get the follow error message:

> type 'SearchErrorAction' is not a subtype of type "FutureOr SearchResultsAction "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just needed to define that the type I wanted to work through the pipe as `dynamic`, like so:

```dart
Stream<dynamic> searchEpic(
  Stream<PerformSearchAction> actions,
  EpicStore<AppState> store,
) {
  return actions.asyncMap<dynamic>((action) => fetchPost()
      .then<dynamic>((results) => SearchResultsAction(results['title']))
      .catchError((error) => SearchErrorAction(error.message)));
}
```